# compare php datetime value with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Compare PHP date and time value with Mysql date and time field

for example,

- PHP code

> $date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

- sql query

> ```
> $sql= "Select * from event_master where create_on='".$date_time."'";
> $result = mysql_query($sql);
> ```

Or other better way to compare php date & time value with sql date & time field value, please suggest me.

I hope someone can give answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Select * From event_master where create_on = STR_TO_DATE('$date_time', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the MySQL Database if it was created on that exact *minutes* & *seconds* too, which won't yield many results. Adjust the query to just `DATE()`, then it will check accordingly dis-regarding the time:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            event_master  
        WHERE 
            DATE( create_on ) = '". $date_time ."'";
```

Lastly, you really should be using `mysqli_` instead of the deprecated `mysql` module.

Answer (score 0):

```
$oDate = new \DateTime();

$zDate = $oDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql= "Select * from event_master where create_on='".$zDate ."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Atleast explain whats going on so others could know.